# Feed training tasks to the LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm going to use LSTM in Keras.
My training examples are U1, U2, ..., Uk with dimension N*Tj which N is a constant and Tj is the length of each sample in Uj. 
Each Uj is a task with Tj training samples. I'm going to feed these k tasks to the network for training. The model should go through U1 (Learn it with back propagation, the batch size is not necessarily T1), then go to the examples inside U2 and learn them, and so on. One epoch is completed at the end of Uk. Uj and U(j+1) are two different tasks and the network should not combine them together during training. (The model should somehow understand the beginning and the end of each task, i.e., it shouldn't consider elements of the next task as the continue of the sequences in the previous task) 
How can I feed this training tasks to the network?

Comment: Any idea? I really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is quite abstract, but I'll do my best to answer your question:

I guess Tj should not change per sample. Typically all samples have the same dimensionality and shape.
It is a bit confusing, because you state, that the dimensionality of the sample is the same as the amount of samples?

Anyway - the real problem you are talking about is, that you would like to feed a network with samples in a specific order and it should solve multiple tasks. The research term you are looking for is `Multi-Task Learning` in Deep Learning.

Those Multi-Task Neural Networks can perform well on **hierarchical tasks** that are **very related to each other**.
If your tasks differ a lot, it might be the best idea to train a neural network per task.